# How to show Google Group name in Google Drive "Who has access"?

Tags: google-drive, google, google-groups

I am new to Google Workspace and have just started using Google Groups. I created a dev group and shared some folders in Google Drive with the group.

The problem is that I cannot check which group has access to the folder because "Unnamed can edit" tells no group name.

My team is very small, so this is fine for now. But if my team gets bigger and more groups are created, it will cause problems.

Any idea to show group names in Google Drive?

[image]